# Does apache poi 5.2.3 supports xmlbeans 5.1.1?

Tags: apache-poi, xmlbeans

I am using poi and poi-ooxml of version 5.2.3 in my project and I am getting this error

```
-java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V.
```

The dependency downloaded `xmlbeans 5.1.1`, When I checked `xmlbeans 5.1.1` the put method is not present. So how can I use `poi 5.2.3`?

**my pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? XmlOptions has 'set' methods, not 'put' - so the issue is with the calling code. poi 5.2.3 was built and tested with xmlbeans 5.1.1. Could you have an old copy of poi on your classpath?